# Vmware Server 2.02 on Ubuntu 9.04 (64-bit) - Performance problems with guest OS/servers!

Tags: vmware-server

Hope someone here can help out as I'm pulling out my hair trying to find a way to get some decent performance from my VM box. I'm running Ubuntu 9.04 64-bit with an AMD 4 Core (phenom) and 4Gb or RAM. I also have another system that is running Ubuntu 9.04 32-bit (a notebook) with 2Gb or RAM. I can run an image on the slower/older dual core notebook lightning fast and take that same image and run it on my VM server and it runs noticeably slower. To make matters worst, when I run 2 server images that I have (that I need to run with some decent performance level) they come up very slowly and can almost cause the host OS to come to a halt/run very slow. If I look at the Ubuntu perfomance monitor it doesn't show a huge load on the CPUs or more than 55-65% RAM usage but it still runs like it's about to die. So... Here are my questions:

1. Are there any know issues with the setup I have that would cause such bad performance?
2. Should I be running something other than VMware 2.02?
3. Should I be running some other host OS?
4. Is there any way to change/modify settings some place to fix this?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Is this a new machine or an old one which has run VMware server before?

If it's a new one, have you checked the BIOS to enable VT Technology or "AMD-V" or similar, the BIOS often lists it under different random headings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware Server 2 dumped its ability to be managed via the VMware Server Console application in favour of a Tomcat servlet, causing its disk space, CPU, and memory usage to balloon compared to version 1. Whether it's a plot to encourage users to shell out for VMware ESX or just poor judgement, I'd recommend reverting to VMware Server 1.10.

Answer (score 1):

I recently installed 2.01 on CentOS 5.3 and wasn't very happy with its stability and management capability.  I upgraded the OS to 5.4 and it got worse.  Upgradinging to 2.02 didn't help.  It got to the point that guests would randomly crash and most of the time I couldn't start them.  I went back to 1.10 (my standard is 1.09) and have had no trouble at all on the exact same hardware and OS.